# How quickly can we detect if a digit is in a number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

If we suppose that we have a number $n$ in base $b$, represented as a power series:

$$n = d_0 b^0 + d_1 b^1 + d_2 b^2 + \dots$$

...where the $d_k$'s are the digits, how quickly can we determine if any of the digits are $b-1$?  In other words, how (quickly) can we decide if there is a $d_k$ such that $d_k = b-1$?

Comment: How is the number represented? It sounds like it's given by the above expansion, in which case it's a trivial problem. Should we assume a binary representation?

Comment: @Sharkos:  It is indeed represented by the expansion above, but I may be able to find other representations for it.  The number is ludicrously large, so I'm hoping that your trivial method is very fast.  In other words, I'm hoping that I don't have to look at all the digits; that maybe a faster method exists.

Comment: What do you know about the number $n$? If the number is rational, then you just work out the base b expansion till it becomes periodic. The number steps depends on the primes dividing the denominator and the order of b in their multiplicative groups. If $n$ is not rational, I suppose it depends on how $n$ is defined. There exist $n$ where this problem is undecidable.

Comment: The number is a natural or 0.  Again, I'm hoping for something faster than analyzing all the digits...

Comment: Is this question kind of like "Determine if the digit representing 138,903 is in the base 138,904 representation of Graham's number"?

Comment: @Arthur:  The number has $2^n$ digits, so it's not quite as large as Graham's number.  But I'm simply trying to detect if one of the digits is a certain value.

Comment: What exactly is given? Are we given a list containing $d_0, d_1, \ldots$? Do we know anything else about $n$?

Comment: We are given a function $f(b)$ which is a bunch of additions, subtractions, multiplications, and divisions of a function of $b$, which describes a finite series.  For instance, we may have something like $f(b) = (1+b)(1+b^2) + (1+2 b^3)$.  This is of course equal to $2+b+b^2+3b^3$.  So in this case $d_0=2, d_1=1, d_2=1, d_3=3$.  ALSO, we know that $b-1$ can only occur at every $m$th digit.  In other words, only $d_0, d_m, d_{2m}, d_{3m}$, etc. can be $b-1$.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way of doing this is to use the following algorithm, which I describe using Python.

```
def digitIsPresent(n, d, base):
   while n > 0:
       if n % d == 0:
            return True
       n /= d
  return False
```

This runs in $O(n)$ time where $n$ is the number of digits.  I don't think you are likely to find anything faster than it.

Comment: I don't think it runs in $O(\text{nr digits})$ time: it can require up to $\text{nr digits}$ division operations, each of which taking $O(\text{nr digits})$ time.